# Can I marshal data from a C/C++ struct into a C# struct with properties?

Tags: c#, struct, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a C# struct which is used for interfacing with some native code. Let's say it looks like this and there's an entry point in the dll that can be used to retrieve values for this struct:

```cs
public struct MyNativeStruct 
{
    public double ExampleField;
}

[DllImport("SomeDll")]
public static extern MyNativeStruct GetMyNativeStruct();
```

The struct is used to get structured values out of a native dll i.e. it mirrors a struct in the dll. This is all marshalling properly, so I can use the values just fine in my .NET application.

Later on, I've come to a situation where I really need a struct (or object) that has properties rather than fields so what I *really* want is something that looks more like this:

```cs
struct MyNativeStruct 
{
    public double ExampleField { get; set; }
}
```

Now of course I could just wrap the `extern` method which gets the struct from the dll and then convert it to an object with properties like this:

```cs
public sealed class MyNativeClass 
{
    public double ExampleField { get; set; }
}

// Some quick and dirty function to get values from MyNativeStruct.
public static MyNativeClass GetMyNativeClass() 
{
    var nativeStruct = GetMyNativeStruct();
    return new MyNativeClass { ExampleField = nativeStruct.ExampleField };
}
```

But this means I will have to create 2 types for each native struct that I want to retrieve from the dll so I was hoping that there may be some nice way to just marshal the native struct into a .NET struct with properties instead of fields.

I suppose it could also be possible to create the struct with the public fields first which are backed by properties also in the struct.

Anyway, I was wondering if there was some standard, idiomatic or built-in way to marshal native struct types into C# struct types that have properties rather than public fields.

Comment: Auto-implemented properties are backed up with auto-created fields. These will get marshaled. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7068911/11683.

Comment: Why do you need properties? If you're using the struct for anything other than marshalling, it's probably best to have one struct for marshalling and one object for everything else: structs for marshalling often need special treatment in the way that they're used, manual calls to `Marshal` to populate various things, etc -- they're not the sort of things you'd pass around the rest of an application.

Comment: @GSerg I don't believe that auto-implemented backing fields are subject to the same struct field ordering rules as explicitly-defined fields. In fact, that's exactly what the answer you linked to says. So that will *not* work (it will get marshalled, but incorrectly)

Comment: @canton7 I never said they would be marshalled correctly. I probably should have been more clear that the effect is to be avoided.

Comment: @GSerg for the link it was pretty useful, but my concern is exactly what canton7 has pointed out.

Comment: @MattB The link tells you to declare the backing field explicitly, so just do that.

Comment: In the general case, no, you'll have to declare structs specially crafted for interop (attributes, IntPtr instead of arrays, depends on in/out, etc.) and recreate "nice" .NET classes over that if you don't want to hand over these structs for public consumption. You can build tools (generators, etc.) if you have a lot of structs like that. PS: returning a struct from a .DLL call won't work in the general case, you'll have to pass it as a ref (in/out) argument. You can think it works if the struct size is less than 64 bits (which is the case of MyNativeStruct ) and your running x64.

Comment: Just declare the backing fields explicitly.

Comment: @Simon Mourier your latter point is a pretty interesting one, do you have a link to a resource explaining it so I can investigate that further? The actual structs I am passing are a fair amount larger than 64 bits and I am on x64. Although everything is working for me so far. Cheers.

Comment: @Simon I'm reasonably sure that's incorrect. Please provide a source.

Comment: @canton7 I would guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845305/11683.

Comment: Right, so "needs care" not "won't work"

Comment: It's not a problem in my case, but useful information to keep in mind so thanks for that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes here in future, my solution was to add the properties after the struct fields (as suggested by GSerg, David Heffernan and Simon Mourier in the comments).

So my struct now looks a little something like this:

```cs
struct MyNativeStruct 
{
    private double ExampleField;
    public double ExampleProperty => ExampleField;
}
```

Comment: Why? Make the field private as usual, and have a normal property with get and set. Currently you have a readable-writable field and a function that only returns its contents. That's pretty confusing.

Comment: My bad I was on auto pilot, but I only need the getter for my purposes.